# Compact operator maps weakly convergent sequences into strongly convergent sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I found the following property of compact operators in a proof, and I can't prove it.

> Prove that if $T \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ is compact, and if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ (the sequence converges weakly to $u$ in $\sigma(E,E^*)$) then $Tu_n \to Tu$ strongly in $F$.

I was able to prove that $Tu_n$ has a convergent subsequence ($u_n \rightharpoonup u$ implies that $(u_n)$ is bounded in $E$. Then, because $T$ is compact it must follow that $(Tu_n)$ must contain some strong convergent subsequence), but didn't manage to finalize the proof.

Any reference or hints are welcome.

Comment: @all: please ignore my vote to close. I'm pretty sure this was discussed several times already, but I can't seem to find the thread at the moment. The thread I linked to is *not* a duplicate of this question. Beni, sorry about that.

Comment: @t.b.: It's ok. I was wondering why it was voted to close. I also searched the site before posting, and didn't find it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Make use of the following topological lemma.

**Lemma** Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathbf{x}=(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of elements of $X$. If every subsequence of $\mathbf{x}$ contains a subsequence convergent to $x$ then $x_n \to x$.

Comment: This surely is a very nice argument. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! This little lemma is simple yet useful to know, IMHO.

Comment: One of the most beautiful and useful techniques in analysis and problems in sequences. I love it

Comment: I don't understand how this lemma can help us? The lemma speaks about every subsequence. While we found only one convergent subsequence?

Comment: @Kamil: you have to apply this lemma to an arbitrary subsequence of $u_n$. Since $u_n$ is bounded, and since $T$ is compact, however you choose a subsequence of $u_n$ there is a sub-subsequence of $Tu_n$ that converges. By assumption, each and every one of these sub-subsequences converge to the same limit. This is, roughly speaking, how you should reason. Hope this helps

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro could you add some more detail on how to use this? The strong convergence of every sub-subsequence to some limit $u$ will help you conclude that the subsequence from which the sub-subsequence was drawn has that limit $u$. How does one conclude that $u$ is the limit of the full sequence?

Answer (score 18):

This is also true by the following reason:

Since you've already proved that there is a strongly convergent subsequence, let's say $ Tu_{n_k} \to u^* $ for $ k \to \infty $. Then by the weak convergence of $ u_n \rightharpoonup u $ you get immediately that $ Tu_n \rightharpoonup Tu $. 
Now since strong convergence implies weak convergence and from the uniqueness of the limit of a weak convergent sequence it must be true that

$ u^*= Tu $.

Therefore $ Tu $ is a limit point of the sequence $ (Tu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $.
Now there's just one thing left to prove your statement

Claim: There's no other limit point, hence it must be the limit.

Proof: Suppose there's another limit point $ z $ of the sequence $ (Tu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $. Again there must be a subsequence $ (Tu_{n_m})_{m \in \mathbb{N}} $ converging to $ z $. Hence this subsequence $ u_{n_m} \rightharpoonup u$.
Last step, use the same argumentation as above to conclude that $ z = Tu = u^*$.

Therefore $ Tu_n \to Tu $ as $ n\to \infty $.

To be precise, at this point you know that

$ Tu_{n_k} \to Tu $ and that the limit $ Tu $ is the only limit point of $ (Tu_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $. Use now a contradiction argument to prove that $ Tu_n\to Tu $.

Comment: Why is it "immediate" that you get $Tu_n \rightharpoonup Tu$ from the weak convergence of the $u_n$?

Comment: @maximumtag what is your definition of weak convergence?

Comment: @maximumtag you can also use this fact: a linear operator is (norm to norm ) continuous if and only if it is weak to weak continuous. [ see Megginson "An introduction to Banach space theory", theorem 2.5.11].
In this context,  a compact operator is of course continuous.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Hi Martin, what you are talking about seems to be the weak-$*$ convergence unless the bracket means inner product, but our spaces may not be Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @SamWong: it's hard to know what I was talking about a year and a half ago since the question I was answering has been deleted. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: In what sense is $Tu$ a limit point of $(Tu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$? It appears to me that $Tu$ is a weak limit of $Tu_n$.

Comment: Interestingly enough, uniqueness of weak limits requires Hahn-Banach