# Convergence in $L^1$ space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

> Suppose that $f_{n}$ is a sequence of measurable functions, in a finite measure space, $f_{n}\to f $ in $m$-measure and that there exists $g$ in $L^1$ such that $\vert f_n\vert \le g$.
>   Prove that 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to +\infty}\Vert f_n-f\Vert_{L^1}=0.
> $$

What I obviously thought of doing was splitting the difference $|f_n-f|$  to the less than and greater than $\epsilon$ and bound the greater part by $2g$. I am stuck right there, I can show it is finite but can not show it is less than epsilon.

Next I thought of using the R. Fisher's argument of getting the subsequence of $f_n$ which converges a.e, and finiteness of space give you a. uniform by Egoroff). But that way I can only show result will be good for the case of subsequence. I am not sure if I can conclude from there though( by arguing that original sequence and its subsequence goes to the same limit).
I am sure I am missing something here. I would love to get out of this confusion. Help please.

Comment: The subsequence argument can be put to work. You could try proving that any subsequence of $(f_n)$ has a subsequence which converges to $f$ in $L^1$, then apply [this lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/70411/8157).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.    Show there is $\delta > 0$ such that $\int_A (|g|+|f|) \ dm < \epsilon/3$ for any measurable set $A$ with $m(A) < \delta$.
Also there is a set $C$ such that $m(C) < \infty$ and $\int_{C^c} (|g| + |f|)\ dm < \epsilon/3$.  Now since $f_n \to f$ in measure, for sufficiently large $n$ we have $|f_n - f| <  \epsilon/(3 m(C))$ except on a set $B_n$
of measure $< \delta$.  So for sufficiently large $n$,
$$ \int |f_n - f| \ dm \le \int_{B_n} |f_n - f| \ dm + \int_{C^c} |f_n - f|\ dm +
\int_C \frac{\epsilon}{3 m(C)} \ dm \le \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{3} =\epsilon $$

Comment: "Also there is a set $C$ such that $m(C) < \infty$ and $\int_{C^c} (|g| + |f|)\ dm < \epsilon/3$" Why?

Comment: Actually you don't need this part since you're given that it is a finite measure space.  But in any $\sigma$-finite measure space you can get it by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.