# Is following option is correct or incorrect?

Tags: general-topology

Which of the following statements are true?

(a). Let $X$ be a set equipped with two topologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$. Assume that any
given sequence in $X$ converges with respect to the topology $\tau_1$ if, and only
if, it also converges with respect to the topology $\tau_2$. Then $\tau_1 = \tau_2$.

(b). Let $(X, \tau_1)$ and $(Y, \tau_2)$ be two topological spaces and let $f : X \to Y$ be a
given map. Then $f$ is continuous if, and only if, given any sequence $\{x_n\}$
such that $x_n \to x \in X$, we have $f(x_n) \to f(x) \in Y$.

(c). Let $(X, \tau )$ be a compact topological space and let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence
in $X$. Then, it has a convergent subsequence.

My attempsts ; all option a) ,b) and c) are all correct... by theorem  of Arzelà–Ascoli theorem ...

Is my answer is correct or not ? and i would be more thankful who rectifying my mistakes........

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: No, not all three are correct, and Arzelà-Ascoli doesn't apply to any of these as far as I can tell from a quick glance.

Comment: Look for counter examples in spaces that are not 1st countable.

Answer (score 0):

In $b)$ the $" \Leftarrow"$ part is not always true unless $(X,\tau)$ is a first countable space.

Here is a counterexample:

[sequentially continuous on a non first-countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351987/sequentially-continuous-on-a-non-first-countable)

$c)$ is not always true.Here is a reference for counterexample.  The space $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ which is compact from Tychonov's theorem.

https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/calmost/pdfs/sasms_F04.pdf

Comment: thanks @ marios Gretsas