# About relation between continuity and sequentially continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Its is known every continuous function between topological spaces is sequentially continuous. Also sequentially continuity implies continuity if the domain space is first countable. I am interested in example of the function between topological spaces (where domain space is not first countable, as I say) that is sequentially continuous but not continuous.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351987/sequentially-continuous-on-a-non-first-countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\mathbb R$, consider the topology $\tau$ for which a set $A$ is open if and only if $A=\emptyset$ or $A^\complement$ is countable. Let $\tau_d$ be the discrete topology. For both of them, a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to some $x$ if and only of $x_n=x$ if $n$ is large enough. So, the identity from $(\mathbb R,\tau)$ into $(\mathbb R,\tau_d)$ is sequentially continuous. But it is not continuous, of course. For instance, $(0,1)$ is an open subset of $(\mathbb R,\tau_d)$, but not of $(\mathbb R,\tau)$.