# Compact Operators: Weak Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

**Problem**

Given Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Consider a compact operator $C\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$.

Then weak convergence is turned into strong convergence:
$$x_n\rightharpoonup x\implies Cx_n\to Cx$$
I'd like to try proving it but would need some hints.

**Attempt**

Denote the sup-norm by:
$$F:\Omega\to E:\quad\|F\|_\Omega:=\sup_{\omega\in\Omega}\|F(\omega)\|_E$$

Weak convergence is preserved under continuous operators:
$$\|l(Cx_n-Cx)\|=\|(C'l)(x_n-x)\|\to0$$
By uniform boundedness principle weak convergence implies boundedness:
$$x_n\rightharpoonup x:\quad\|l(x)\|_\mathbb{N}<\infty\implies\|x\|_\mathbb{N}<\infty$$
Hence one can exploit compactness of the operator:
$$(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ bounded}\implies C(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ precompact}$$
And one obtains strongly convergent subsequences.

Should I combine these now and how?

Comment: @TomCooney: Yeah true. Can you help me anyway?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/compact-operator-maps-weakly-convergent-sequences-into-strongly-convergent-seque).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general principle, if we have a unique possible limit, together with some form of sequential compactness, we get convergence. This is a corollary of the following: $x_n \to x$ if and only if for every subsequence  $(x_{n_k})$, there is a further subsequence $x_{n_{k_j}} \to x$ (To prove the less obvious implication, suppose it doesn't converge and consider a sequence bounded away from $x$ by some $\epsilon > 0$).

We can apply this to the given problem as follows: $Tx_n \rightharpoonup Tx$ by continuity. Thus if any subsequence has a strong limit, it certainly is $Tx$. But compactness guarantees every subsequence has a subsequence that converges to something: that something is $Tx$ by uniqueness, and so by our above equivalence with convergence, we have $Tx_n \to Tx$.

Comment: Ah ok so one derives a contradiction by: $x_n\nrightarrow x:\quad\|x_{n_k}-x\|\geq\varepsilon,\|x_{n_{k_j}}-x\|\to0$

Comment: Ah and knowing that it converges weakly one has a unique limit for strongly convergent subsequences and compactness gives the rest.