# Bounded operator and image of convergent net is compact implies compact operator

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators, nets

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces with $X$ reflexive. I now have a bounded operator $T \colon X \to Y$ that also has the property that if $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ is a bounded net that weakly converges, then the net $(Tx_i)_{i \in I}$ is convergent in norm. I now have to prove that $T$ is a compact but I have no idea on how to start.

Comment: [The proofs from this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70410/81360) should work.  Also, correct me if I'm wrong: isn't a weakly-convergent net necessarily bounded?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom consider $( t^{-1})_{t\in I}$ with $I=(0,+\infty)$ and the usual order so that the limit is zero

Comment: @daw ah that's a great example, thanks