# Clarifying when a weak limit can be assumed to be a strong limit

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

In the second answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/compact-operator-maps-weakly-convergent-sequences-into-strongly-convergent-seque) post this it is stated:

> Since you've already proved that there is a strongly convergent subsequence, let's say $ Tu_{n_k} \to u^* $ for $ k \to \infty $. Then by the weak convergence of $ u_n \rightharpoonup u $ you get immediately that $ Tu_n \rightharpoonup Tu $.
> Now since strong convergence implies weak convergence and from the uniqueness of the limit of a weak convergent sequence it must be true that $$ u^*= Tu $$

I understand the uniqueness of weak limits to mean if $ Tu_n \rightharpoonup Tu $ and $ Tu_n \rightharpoonup Tu' $ then $Tu = Tu'$. But should that mean the strong limit, $u^*$, should also coincide with $Tu$? This seems like a stronger statement, I'm not quite understanding the logic of how to go back to the strong limit.

Comment: You dont go back to the strong limit: Since $Tu_{n_k} \to u^*$ you get that $Tu_{n_k} \rightharpoonup u^*$. But you also have that $Tu_{n_k} \rightharpoonup Tu$

Comment: Okay so the idea is that $Tu_{n_k}$ converges to some $u^*$. That $u^*$ is found to be $Tu$ (because every weak subsequence is converging to $Tu$). So $Tu_{n_k} \rightarrow Tu$