# Weak convergence in Sobolev space $W^{1,p}$ implies strong convergence in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $p\neq \infty$ and let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be a regular domain (a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary). I want to prove that

> If $\{u_n\}$ weakly converges in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then it converges in $L^p(\Omega)$.

**My attempt**

By definition if $\{u_n\}$ weakly converges in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then it weakly converges in $L^p(\Omega)$ too and this implies (by Banach-Steinhaus theorem) that $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $L^p(\Omega)$. The same reasoning applies to the gradient of $u$ so $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

By Rellich Kondrachov theorem there exists a subsequence of $\{u_n\}$ that converges in $L^p(\Omega)$. So I basically have

- $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$
- $u_{n_k}\to u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$

Is this enough to establish the strong convergence? If yes why?

Secondly, I was trying to construct a counterexample if $p=\infty$, but without any success. Could you help me?

Comment: It doesn't seam detailed enough, it basically just says "apply Rellich Kondrachov"... also it doesn't address the counterexample part...

Comment: Under the regularity assumptions on $\Omega$, the result is true for $p=\infty$, since in this case $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is exactly the class of bounded Lipschitz functions in $\Omega$, so you can apply the Arzelá-Ascoli theorem in place of Rellich-Kondrachov.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as here the OP asked about the case $p==q$.

Comment: Honestly, I do not understand, what your are asking. At which step do you have doubts?

Comment: @daw I'm basically just asking: is it true that if a sequence $\{u_n\}$ weakly converges in $L^p(\Omega)$ to $u$ and admits a subsequence that converges in $L^p(\Omega)$ to $u$ then $\{u_n\}$ converges in $L^p(\Omega)$ to $u$?

Comment: This is not true. But you know more: $(u_n)$ converges weakly in $W^{1,p}$. This is enough to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is false, since the Rellich Kondrachov theorem has two different exponents:
$W^{1,p}\subset\subset L^q$ for all $1\leq q<p^*$, assuming $1\leq p<n$ ($p=\infty$ is not allowed! If you want a counterexample, look at the counterexample for the Rellich Kondrachov Theorem)

To complete the proof, one only needs to know that the inclusion map in the Rellich Kondrachov Theorem is compact: $W^{1,p}\subset\subset L^q$. Therefore, weakly $W^{1,p}$ convergent sequences are mapped to strongly $L^q$ convergent sequences. This is what you wanted to prove.
If you want to understand this fact about compact operators, look at this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/compact-operator-maps-weakly-convergent-sequences-into-strongly-convergent-seque).

Comment: In fact I asked how to justify the last step

Comment: I will think about the last step, but anyways I think it is very that there are two different exponents $p$ and $q$.

Comment: I edited it now. Your last step is actually the first step of [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70410/compact-operator-maps-weakly-convergent-sequences-into-strongly-convergent-seque).

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two versions of the [Rellich-Kondrachov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem). The second one on that wiki page is just the answer to the question. The first version is the following: $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded into $L^q(\Omega)$ if $q<p^*$ and $p<n$. Since $p^*>p$ this answers the question for $p<n$.

For $p\ge n$, one can use that $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ embeds (trivially) into $W^{1,n-\epsilon}(\Omega)$. Now the first version of Rellich-Kondrachov is applicable, and yields the compact embedding into $L^p(\Omega)$ provided $\epsilon$ is small enough. This uses that $p^* \to \infty$ for $p\nearrow n$.

This shows that the embedding operator of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ into $L^p(\Omega)$ is compact for *all* $p$, and so sequences converging weakly in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ converge strongly in $L^p(\Omega)$.